How can expand DD by default on laravel 11?
Can the dd() function, which uses vardumper, be configured to automatically expand a set number of levels for display, eliminating the need to manually drill down each time you want to inspect an object or array in greater detail?

Using this answer and checking the source code of Laravel it shows that the framework makes use of Symfony's var-dumper package for the dd function.
You may create a new helper function extending the var-dumper package to expand the number of levels.

app/helpers.php

<?php

use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Caster\ReflectionCaster;
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Caster\ScalarStub;
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\HtmlDumper;
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\VarCloner;
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper;

if (!function_exists('dda')) {
    function dda(mixed ...$vars): never
    {
        if (!\in_array(\PHP_SAPI, ['cli', 'phpdbg', 'embed'], true) && !headers_sent()) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
        }

        VarDumper::setHandler(function ($var, ?string $label = null) {
            $cloner = new VarCloner();
            $cloner->addCasters(ReflectionCaster::UNSET_CLOSURE_FILE_INFO);
            $dumper =\in_array(\PHP_SAPI, ['cli', 'phpdbg', 'embed'], true) ? new CliDumper() : new HtmlDumper();

            // Configures the maximum number of items that will be cloned past the minimum nesting depth.
            // Items are counted using a breadth-first algorithm so that lower level items have higher priority than deeply nested items.
            // Specifying -1 removes the limit.
            $cloner->setMaxItems(-1);

            $var = $cloner->cloneVar($var);

            if (null !== $label) {
                $var = $var->withContext(['label' => $label]);
            }

            // Setting a high value to display all the depth
            $dumper->setDisplayOptions([ 'maxDepth' => 999999999 ]);
            $dumper->dump($var);
        });

        if (!$vars) {
            VarDumper::dump(new ScalarStub(''));

            exit(1);
        }

        if (array_key_exists(0, $vars) && 1 === count($vars)) {
            VarDumper::dump($vars[0]);
        } else {
            foreach ($vars as $k => $v) {
                VarDumper::dump($v, is_int($k) ? 1 + $k : $k);
            }
        }

        exit(1);
    }
}

Have the new helper function available to use by adding it to the autoload files. Reference

composer.json

"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/helpers.php"
    ]
},

Once the file is auto-loaded, the function may be used. If not you may need to issue the command
composer dump-autoload

After which the function may be used:

routes/web.php

use App\Models\User;

Route::get('/', function () {
    dda(User::all());
});

References:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/7.1/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/VarDumper.php

